# Bouncycastle Install Provider Programmatically

Tags: java, security, policy, bouncycastle

Is it possible to install Bouncycastle provider programmaticly without modifying security policy file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sure:

```
    java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: tried that that throws an exception. Docs for bouncy castle says i need to edit the security.policy file. I was wondering to do it programaticly.

Comment: nvm thanks i forgot to import java.security.Security should get some sleep.

Comment: This ends up throwing a NoSuchAlgorithmException CAST5/OpenPGPCFB/NoPadding.  I follow the exception down and it doesn't appear to be happening in the bouncy castle packages.  It looks like it happens in javax.  Any help here?