# Dynamic bouncycastle provider registration failure

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, bouncycastle

For my tasks I need to have very small test project, that would just do some ECC operations.

For this I've decided to use bouncycastle. Since there is quite a lot of java snippets I was surprised, that dynamic provider adding not working as expected.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/FtL5jAds) is full code, and this is how it looks in IJ:

[image]

So, the question is: how do I resolve all needed functions, especially [`addProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286837/bouncycastle-install-provider-programmatically)?

I'm using maven for this project and here is my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/vCLdUSDD)

**Update:**

```
Error:(11, 29) java: <identifier> expected
Error:(11, 30) java: illegal start of type
Error:(11, 33) java: ')' expected
Error:(11, 54) java: ';' expected
Error:(11, 55) java: illegal start of type
Error:(11, 56) java: <identifier> expected
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: You need to put your code in a main method now, don't you?

public static void main()

Comment: @vagelis thanks, nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vagelis comments you're missing `main` method, and some imports.

Also `java.security.Security.addProvider()` is in the *jdk* itself so there is no extra dependency needed in the *pom.xml*.

Your code corrected could be:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.ECFieldFp;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.EllipticCurve;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECPointUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String args[]){

            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            EllipticCurve curve = new EllipticCurve(
            new ECFieldFp(new BigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308885314476597252960362792450860609699839")), // q
            new BigInteger("7fffffffffffffffffffffff7fffffffffff8000000000007ffffffffffc", 16), // a
            new BigInteger("6b016c3bdcf18941d0d654921475ca71a9db2fb27d1d37796185c2942c0a", 16)); // b
            ECParameterSpec spec = new ECParameterSpec(
            curve,
            ECPointUtil.decodePoint(curve, Hex.decode("020ffa963cdca8816ccc33b8642bedf905c3d358573d3f27fbbd3b3cb9aaaf")), // G
            new BigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308884807550341691627752275345424702807307"), // n
            1); // h

            ECPrivateKeySpec priKey = new ECPrivateKeySpec(
            new BigInteger("876300101507107567501066130761671078357010671067781776716671676178726717"), // d
            spec);
            ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(
            ECPointUtil.decodePoint(curve, Hex.decode("025b6dc53bc61a2548ffb0f671472de6c9521a9d2d2534e65abfcbd5fe0c70")), // Q
            spec);
        }
}
```